# How to generate a random field with truncated marginal distributions?

Tags: r, simulation, spatial, truncated, geor

Is there an R package or functions which can generate a random field with truncated distributions?

I am trying to simulate a lognormal spatial random field but I need the simulated value in a certain range. So I need some easy to use functions to generate a truncated Gaussian field to start with. To be specific, I need a function like `GaussRF` from the RandomFields package or `grf` from the geoR package to generate a random field with truncated marginal distributions and a correlation structure with a specified range direclty.

If there is no availabe read-to-use functions or packages,is it possible that I write my own very easily?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you make a more specific example? For instance, are you looking for a function analogous to `rlnorm` that instead returns a random number from a truncated log-normal instead of a log-normal? Or are you looking for an analogue to `dlnorm` (the density function)?

Comment: @DavidRobinson thanks for the quick reply. No, I am not looking for a function to generate a truncated distribution, but a function like `GaussRF` in the RandomFieds package to generate a truancated random field directly.

Comment: You need to explain why you cannot simply truncate a (non-truncated) random field at the bounds of your specification. This is known as "rejection sampling".

Comment: To add to DWin's comment: if you can write the distribution function, you can easily use it as the weighting function argument `prob` in the function `sample` .

Comment: this doesn't strike me as a necessarily simple question.  Multivariate normal distributions have very special properties, and it's not guaranteed that there's any easy way to generate a spatial random field with the desired correlation structure *and* a marginal truncated lognormal distribution (although even exponentiating, i.e. generating the lognormal from the normal, modifies the variance-covariance structure)

Comment: as @BenBolker said, I need to generate a spatial random filed with desired correlation structure, like the correlation length or range, variogram model. I do know how to generate samples from a truncated distribution, but I do not know how to generate a spatially correlated truncated field.